# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY in testclass

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest
Public class BureaucracyFeedbackDetailscontrollerTest  {

public static testmethod void mytest1(){   
  Test.StartTest();
   Community community = [ SELECT Id FROM Community WHERE Name = 'Bureaucracy Feedback' ];


   //Create Idea
   Idea ideaToCreate = new Idea();
   ideaToCreate.Title = 'TestIdea';
   ideaToCreate.CommunityId = community.id;

   insert ideaToCreate;

   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',ideaToCreate.Id);
  apexpages.standardcontroller sc=new apexpages.standardcontroller(ideaToCreate);
  BureaucracyFeedbackDetailscontroller bfc = new BureaucracyFeedbackDetailscontroller(sc);
  bfc.getCount();
  bfc.count1();
  bfc.count2();
  bfc.goBackToPrevPage();
  bfc.incrementCounter();
Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

While running this class I am getting error as:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id:

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I believe you get it due to mistake in your code. Can you post more code with line numbers, as well as stack trace?

Comment: I am getting this error on this line  insert ideaToCreate;                                
Detailed error:System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: Do you have access on that record?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be because your test method cannot access data in your org because you have not mentioned  **see** **all** **data** equals to true or it could be a security issue.

I would suggest checking the following:

Check your API Version is less than version 24.0. Later API versions will not give you access to org data by default.      Consider creating records in the test method, or use annotation @isTest(SeeAllData=true) at the top of your test class.

Or you need to insert community and then assign id of community to idea.
Your problem will get resolve. Once done,  mark it as your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... Tried the solution doesn't work...

Comment: Did you tried inserting community in your code..  Then assigning the community id to idea..  And bring test.Start() after insert ideaTocreate. Also put debug for community id and ideaTocreate.id.. Chcek weather are getting inserted or not..

Comment: I am not able to insert community getting field not writeable error.

Comment: Create one custom portal user and run your test class as that user. Also if you are querying the community record.. Try without any filter with limit 1 and above the test class add annotation (seealldata=true)